# How to render plain text to HTML in CommandController in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

What I want is to convert a plain text to HTML code, something like `some plain text` to `<p>some plain text</p>`

I tried the `ContentObjectRenderer` as following

```
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer $contentObject */
$contentObject = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class);

return $contentObject->parseFunc($bodytext, array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE');
```

however, it doesn't work at all. Do I have to initialize `$GLOBALS['TSFE']`or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look into the `HtmlViewHelper.php`. You will see that they work with a `simulateFrontendEnvironment()` method to build up `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` and remove it after cObj processing.

```
/**
 * Copies the specified parseFunc configuration to $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup in Backend mode
 * This somewhat hacky work around is currently needed because the parseFunc() function of \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer relies on those variables to be set
 */
protected static function simulateFrontendEnvironment()
{
    self::$tsfeBackup = isset($GLOBALS['TSFE']) ? $GLOBALS['TSFE'] : null;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = new \stdClass();
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl = new \stdClass();
    $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
    $configurationManager = $objectManager->get(ConfigurationManagerInterface::class);
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);
}
```

Copy everything you need into your extension and it should work

Comment: it works partially, but t3 links like t3://page?uid=534 will not be parsed, but removed instead